# Karatzas and Shreve proof : An increasing random sequence $A$ is predictable if it is natural

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I have difficulty understanding the proof of the below proposition from Karatzas and Shreve.

I am very confused with the martingale $M$ given. How is this a martingale? How do we get $E[M_k | \mathscr{F}_n] = sgn [A_n - E(A_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1})]$ for $k>n$ and 
$E[sgn[A_n - E(A_n|\mathscr{F}_{n-1})] | \mathscr{F}_k] = E(M_n | \mathscr{F}_k)$ for $k =0,1,\dots, n$?

For instance, for $k>n$ we have $E[M_k | \mathscr{F}_n] = E[M_n | \mathscr{F}_n] = M_n$. For it to be a martingale, we should have $M_n = sgn[A_n - E(A_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1})]$. But how does this hold?

And, we should also have $E[sgn[A_n - E(A_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1}) | \mathscr{F}_{n-1}] = E(M_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1})$. 
I can't see how these hold.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of a "natural" sequence of random variables?

Comment: It is Definition 4.2 in the excerpt I have attached.

Comment: Ah, I see. The formula reminds me of the martingale transform, except the increments are from the increasing sequence $A_n$ and the other term in the summand is $M_{k-1}$.

Comment: So we agree that what is proved here is that if $A$ is natural then $A_n=E[A_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ almost surely. Using the fact that conditional expectation is defined only up negligible sets the claim is proved, no need to have property on the filtration (like usual hypothesis).

Comment: @TheBridge The definition of conditional expectation requires the a.e. unique function to be measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$. Here we simply have $A_n = Y$ a.e. for a $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable function $Y=E[A_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1}]$. How does this ensure that $A_n$ is also $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$ measurable?

Comment: You are right but I don't think we care : suppose it's not $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable then there exists a negligible set N s.t. (surely) $A_n=E[A_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] + N$ and N is not in  $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$. The point is that $E[N|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=0$ a.s. so even if $A_n$ is not $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable we don't "care" as it has not impact when conditioning. So if $A$ is natural it a.s. equal to $E[A_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ and "almost"  $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable, and truly measurable if $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ is complete.

Comment: In "Kruglov - On Natural and Predictable Processes" the result is proved in continuous time and the author imposes the usual conditions so the filtration at time 0 is complete. So I don't know but it might be the case, that this is a very important condition in the continuous time setting.

Comment: As for your first question about martingale property for  $M$, it seems quite easy to see we have to check that $E[M_r|F_u]=M_u$ for $r>u$. You have to treat this case by case. So if $r>u\ge n$ $M_r=M_n$ so  $E[M_r|F_u]=E[M_n|F_u]$, but $M_n$ is $F_u$-measurable so $E[M_n|F_u]=M_n=M_u$. Now if $r\ge n>u$, then $E[M_r|F_u]=E[M_n|F_u]=M_u$ by definition of $M_u$ for u<n. and if $n>r>u$ then $E[M_r|F_u]=E[E[M_n|F_r]|F_u]=E[M_n|F_u]$ by  tower property of conditional expectation and $E[M_n|F_u] =M_u$. You are done unless mistaken.

Comment: @TheBridge I am not sure about the case $r \ge n >u$. Now, if $r>n>u$ then as you wrote we have $E[M_r | F_u] = E[M_n|F_u]=M_u$. But if $r=n>u$, then $E[M_r|F_u]= E[sgn[A_n - E(A_n|F_{n-1})]|F_n]$. This is the case I don't know how to deal with the sign function inside.

Comment: your problematic case is as follow unless mistaken r=n>u: $E[M_r|F_u]=E[M_n|F_u] =E[sgn[A_n - E(A_n|F_{n-1})]|F_u]=M_u$ because -$M_r=M_n=sgn[A_n - E(A_n|F_{n-1})$ and M_u=E[M_n|F_u] by defintion is that all right ?

Comment: @TheBridge I don't understand how you get the last equality. For $u<n$, $M_u$ is $E[M_n|F_u]$ from the original martingale $M$. which is just $M_u$ from martingale property. So why do we get $E[sgn[A_n-E(A_n|F_{n-1})]|F_u] = M_u$?

Comment: Ok this is simply a notation problem M_n  is "defined reletively to the value n, then for k different from n M_k is defined but in no way M_k=sgn[A_k-E(A_k|F_{k-1})] for not equal to n. I think this where you get confused. regards

Comment: @TheBridge Oh I see. So this newly constructed M has nothing to do with the bounded martingale $M$ at the first line of the proof. We just create a new bounded martingale this way.