# If $X = E[X|\mathscr{G}]$ a.e. then $X$ is $\mathscr{G}$ -measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ be a measure space with filtration $\{\mathscr{F}_n\}_{n \in N}$. Let $A_n$ be adapted to the filtration $\mathscr{F}_{n}$, and $E|A_n - E[A_n| \mathscr{F}_{n-1}]|=0$, i.e. $A_n = E[A_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1}]$ a.e -P. How do we get that $A_n$ is $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable from this?

All we have here is that $A_n$ agrees with the $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable function $Y$ that has $\int_C YdP = \int_C A_n dP$ for all $C \in \mathscr{F}_{n-1}$. How do we get that $A_n$ must be $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable as well?

Comment: I don't see how $A_n = \mathbb{E}[A_n ~|~ \mathscr{F}_{n-1}]$ makes sense? Did you mean $A_{n-1} = \mathbb{E}[A_n ~|~ \mathscr{F}_{n-1}]$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist That was a mistake.

Comment: Ok. In which case, you can’t. I don’t even see how you conclude that $A_n = E[A_n \mid \mathscr F_n]$.

Comment: I am a bit surprised by the negative answers. I thought that $E(X| \mathcal F)$ was $\mathcal F$ measurable by definition.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro $\mathsf{E}[X\mid \mathcal{F}]$ is always $\mathcal{F}$-measurable (by definition).

Comment: @d.k.o.: Great, thank you for reassuring me. So, if $X=E(X|\mathcal F)$, obviously $X$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable (actually, this is a if and only if, I suppose). Then, where's the caveat with this question? It must be related with that "almost everywhere".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Actually, conditional expectations are uniquely defined up to $\mathsf{P}\mid_{\mathcal{F}}$-null sets. However, in order for $X$ to be a version of $\mathsf{E}[X\mid \mathcal{F}]$, it must be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Comment: @d.k.o.: And this is an answer to the present question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true unless $\mathcal{G}$ contains all the $\mathsf{P}$-null sets in $\mathcal{F}$ (and $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathsf{P}$-complete). For a counterexample take $\mathcal{G}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ and $X=1_{A}$, where $\mathsf{P}(A)=0$.

---

If $\mathcal{G}$ satisfies the above-mentioned assumption, then for a version $Y$ of $\mathsf{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]$ and any Borel set $B$,
$$
X^{-1}(B)=(X^{-1}(B)\cap N)\cup(Y^{-1}(B)\cap N^{c})\in\mathcal{G},
$$
where $N\equiv\{X\ne Y\}$, and thus $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Comment: I actually got this question from a proof in Karatzas and Shreve. The link is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3463699/135204. There clearly is something wrong with the proof there?

Comment: Note that your statement above is slightly self-contradictory. In your case, your $A$ is very much measurable, so $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ might very well *be* complete, and $(\Omega, \mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$ is trivially complete since $\mathbb{P}$ isn't the $0$-measure. Hence, the problem is much deeper: There might be $\mathcal{F}$-elements, which are $\mathbb{P}$-null sets that are invisible to your $\mathcal{G}$, completeness be damned!

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Similar result (an increasing sequence is predictable if and only if it's natural) appears in Doob's ["Classical Potential Theory and Its Probabilistic Counterpart"](https://books.google.nl/books?id=vXdVqv8HHKMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=classical+potential+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizrraV557mAhXRZVAKHQzaBRcQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=483&f=false) on page 483, where the author assumes that $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains the null sets.

Answer (score 1):

We can't, because the statement is not true.

Assume, that our probability space is $[0,1]$ with its Borel algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and the Lesbegue measure $m$. Let $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,[0,1]\}$ be the trivial algebra. Then, for any $X\in L^1,$ we have $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(X),$ which is almost surely equal to $1_{\mathbb{[0,1]}\setminus \mathbb{Q}}\cdot \mathbb{E}(X),$ which isn't constant and hence, isn't  $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Note that $E(X)=0$ doesn't imply that $X=0$ almost surely unless $X$ is positive.

Comment: I actually got this question from a proof in Karatzas and Shreve. The link is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3463699/135204. There clearly is something wrong with the proof there?

Comment: There is an absolute value in that proof that your question is missing. However, it's still not true that if $X$ is measurable and $Y=X$ a.e. then $Y$ is measurable. However, the author probably means that there is an $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ version of $A$, which *does* follow from there.